# Scanning multiple lines into an array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, scanf

I am looking to write a code which can be implemented on a text file of the following format:

```
(#)string
int int int
```

For example:

```
#wisconsin
20 45 00
#zelda
13 45 20
```

How do I scan this into an array of the following struct:

```
typedef struct{
    char string[99];
    int  first_int;
    int  second_int;
    int  third_int;
} input_t;
```

My current thinking is:

```
input_t mydata[MAX_NAMES];
int count = 0;
while(mydata[count] = scanf("%s %d %d %d", input_t.string, 
    input_t.first_int, input_t.second_int, input_t.third_int,)){
        count++;
}
```

But this isn't working and I'm unsure about how to use the hash to identify the start of a piece of data without actually including it in the string.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  You need to show your best effort so far.  You need to show the structure you're planning to use.  Reading lines with `scanf()` is usually not a good idea; use `fgets()` to read the line and then `sscanf()` to parse it.  Until you add your code to the question (an honest effort), this is unanswerable.  (Please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]) — amongst other things, we need some sample input and expected output.)

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you very much - I've edited it and hopefully it is up to standards now.

Comment: Much better — thank you!

Comment: Note that `%c` only reads a single character.  You need to use `%s` to read a word.  Do you want the `#` symbol stored in the structure?  It's not clear what you think `input_t mydata[];` will do — it is OK as a declaration of an argument to a function, but not as a variable inside a function.  (Also, the state is Wisconsin — no u's in it.)  You need to add a dimension to the definition.

Comment: I'll amend my code to use %s and fix the spelling error - thank you. I would like the # to be removed when scanning into the struct and I was trying to declare the array that I want all of the structs to be stored into with input_t mydata[]; It will be included with my type declarations in the main code but thought its inclusion here would add some clarity to the question - sorry if it didn't!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is roughly what I'd do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char string[99];
    int  first_int;
    int  second_int;
    int  third_int;
} input_t;

enum { MAX_NAMES = 20 };

int main(void)
{
    input_t mydata[MAX_NAMES];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_NAMES; i++)
    {
        if (scanf(" #%s %d %d %d", mydata[i].string, &mydata[i].first_int,
                  &mydata[i].second_int, &mydata[i].third_int) != 4)
            break;
    }
    int count = i;

    for (i = 0; i <  count; i++)
        printf("%s (%d, %d, %d)\n", mydata[i].string, mydata[i].first_int,
                  mydata[i].second_int, mydata[i].third_int);
    return 0;
}
```

For the input file:

```
#wisconsin
20 45 00
#zelda
13 45 20
```

the code shown produces the output:

```
wisconsin (20, 45, 0)
zelda (13, 45, 20)
```

The leading blank in the format string is necessary to skip the newline left behind after reading the three integers.